# MySQL: delete containing sub-select failing

Tags: mysql

I have this statement in MySql:

```
delete from match_custom_field_team_value
where match_id=10648 
      and match_custom_field_id=14917 
      and event_id in (2, 6, 8, 4)
      and team_id in (select mcfv2.team_id from match_custom_field_team_value mcfv2 
                        where mcfv2.match_id=10648 and mcfv2.match_custom_field_id=14917 and mcfv2.event_id=9);
```

When I attempt to run this, I get:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'match_custom_field_team_value' for update in FROM clause
```

Any idea why that is throwing an error, and the best way to rewrite to to avoid the error? (I know I could do it with a temp table, but would rather not go the extra step.)

Thanks,

Jared

Comment: What happens when you use an `AS` statement, like `match_custom_field_team_value AS mcfv2` in your subquery?

Comment: According to the MySql docs, "The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an identifier." Just to verify, though, I tried it and I get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You can not select from table and update/delete from it in one query. It's prohibited, but you can workaround it in dirty way.

```
delete from match_custom_field_team_value
where match_id=10648 
  and match_custom_field_id=14917 
  and event_id in (2, 6, 8, 4)
  and team_id in (
     select * from (
         select mcfv2.team_id from match_custom_field_team_value mcfv2 
            where mcfv2.match_id=10648 and mcfv2.match_custom_field_id=14917 and mcfv2.event_id=9)
     ) as sub
  )
```

Thanks to that MySQL will not operate on same table but on results fetched from that table.
It should work but it's not good way (think eg. about performace).

Also before using this query read more about possible problems here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery (link by @ypercube ).

Comment: Rewrite with `JOIN` is better. This nested subquery way may not always delete the correct number of rows.

Comment: @ypercube It should work exactly as OPs query (except this one will work ;) ).

Comment: See a case where it doesn't work consistently: [Problem with MySQL subquery](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery) Your case will work OK I think as the two parts of the table are totally separated (the ones with 2,4,6,8 and the one with 9) so it's not an issue here. But as you said, it's kind of dirty way.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for link. I'm not using such queries but good to know that there are serious problems with that.

Comment: When I try this, I get "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias".  So far no luck in trying to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate your help, but I have to move on with this, so I rewrote using a temp table

```
drop table if exists tmp_cfs_to_nuke;
create temporary table tmp_cfs_to_nuke(
    team_id INT(11) unsigned
);

insert into tmp_cfs_to_nuke 
    select mcfv2.team_id from match_custom_field_team_value mcfv2 
        where mcfv2.match_id=10648 and mcfv2.match_custom_field_id=14917 and mcfv2.event_id=9;

delete from match_custom_field_team_value
where match_id=10648 
  and match_custom_field_id=14917 
  and event_id in (2, 6, 8, 4)
  and team_id in (
    select team_id from tmp_cfs_to_nuke
 );
```